# Visual Studio Mac 2022 not showing exception information just opening new window Source Not Found

Tags: macos, visual-studio, xamarin, visual-studio-2022

Whenever `Visual Studio Mac 2022` throwing an exception with I am not getting any information in `Application Output` window related to `exception` like name of the error, file name, line number etc. Nothing is showing up.

Below information coming in android project output window

```
[ViewRootImpl@1cc9b28[MainActivity]] ViewPostIme pointer 0
[ViewRootImpl@1cc9b28[MainActivity]] ViewPostIme pointer 1
Loaded assembly: /data/data/T_Order.Android/files/.__override__/Microsoft.CSharp.dll [External]
[s_Order.Androi] Explicit concurrent copying GC freed 23092(2387KB) AllocSpace objects, 6(120KB) LOS objects, 60% free, 4072KB/10216KB, paused 36us,25us total 11.331ms
Binding: 'MyProfileCommand' property not found on ’T_Order.SummaryViewModel', target property: 'Xamarin.Forms.TapGestureRecognizer.Command'
Binding: 'ProceedClickedCommand' property not found on 'T_Order.SummaryViewModel', target property: 'Xamarin.Forms.Button.Command'
Binding: 'SubmitClickedCommand' property not found on ’T_Order.SummaryViewModel', target property: 'Xamarin.Forms.Button.Command'
Binding: 'Messages' property not found on ’T_Order.SummaryViewModel', target property: 'Xamarin.Forms.ListView.ItemsSource'
Binding: 'Messages' property not found on ’T_Order.SummaryViewModel', target property: 'Xamarin.Forms.ListView.ItemsSource'
Binding: 'Messages' property not found on T’_Order.SummaryViewModel', target property: 'Xamarin.Forms.ListView.ItemsSource'
Binding: 'Text' property not found on ’T_Order.TSummaryViewModel', target property: 'Xamarin.Forms.Entry.Text'
Binding: 'SendCommand' property not found on 'T_Order.SummaryViewModel', target property: 'Xamarin.Forms.ImageButton.Command'
[s_Order.Androi] Explicit concurrent copying GC freed 1299(85KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 60% free, 4034KB/10178KB, paused 100us,36us total 27.606ms
[IMM_LC] hsifw() - flags=0, caller=android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow:1846 android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow:1815 crc64720bb2db66fe9.ButtonRenderer_ButtonClickListener.n_onClick:-2 crc647202db43a66fe9.ButtonRenderer_ButtonClickListener.onClick:30 android.view.View.performClick:7792 
[IMM_LC] hsifw() ignore mServedView == null or mServedView.getWindowToken() != windowToken, mServedView :DecorView@add6114[MainActivity]
[ScrollView] initGoToTop
[ScrollView] initGoToTop
[ScrollView] initGoToTop
[ScrollView] initGoToTop
[s_Order.Androi] Compiler allocated 4163KB to compile void android.widget.TextView.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int)
[ScrollView] initGoToTop
[Choreographer] Skipped 239 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
[AbsListView]  in onLayout changed 
[ScrollView]  onsize change changed 
[OpenGLRenderer] Davey! duration=4043ms; Flags=0, FrameTimelineVsyncId=6196650, IntendedVsync=318461124008433, Vsync=318465107341607, InputEventId=0, HandleInputStart=318465107516534, AnimationStart=318465107518148, PerformTraversalsStart=318465109136638, DrawStart=318465143809034, FrameDeadline=318461157341765, FrameInterval=318465107379502, FrameStartTime=16666666, SyncQueued=318465157153877, SyncStart=318465157276534, IssueDrawCommandsStart=318465159417627, SwapBuffers=318465164366169, FrameCompleted=318465167520752, DequeueBufferDuration=24843, QueueBufferDuration=1384219, GpuCompleted=318465167520752, SwapBuffersCompleted=318465166313044, DisplayPresentTime=0,
```

Working on `xamairn.forms` and startup project is `android`. Just below window opening that's all.

[image]

How can I fix this ?

Comment: `Application Output` can be found by browsing `View > Other Windows > Application Output - your project`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**`This issue has been fixed by creating a new breakpoint in visual studio`**. at

```
Debug - New Breakpoint - New Exception Breakpoint
```

Now the project is failing down at the line where the `exception` is throwing.

[image]